# How to properly update the reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

In my initial state I have boards, think of them as groups in a chat room.
`setboard` is a variable use to switch between rooms using

`activeBoard.` =>

```
activeBoard: state.boards[initialState.setBoard],
```

`I map the content of debates easily. The problem comes when I try to update the reducer.`

```
const initialState = {
    setBoard: 'Feed',
    boards : {
        Feed: {
            id: 1,
            debates: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    text: 'This is the most amazing website on the internet.",
                    Images: 'soul.jpg',
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    topic: 'Somebody tell him to shut up',
                    text: "This is the most amazing website on the internet.",
                    Images: 'salt.jpg',
                },
            ],
            invitations: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    nickname: "imhotep",
                    inviteText: ' BLOCKING People block or unfriend their parents on Facebook 
                },
            ],
     }
export const BoardProvider = ({ children}) =>{
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(BoardReducer, initialState) 

    function AddDebates(debates){
        dispatch({
            type: 'Add-debates',
            payload: debates
        })
    }
return ( <BoardContext.Provider value={{
        boards: state.boards,
        
        activeBoard: state.boards[initialState.setBoard],
        debates: activeBoard.debates,
        AddDebates
    }}>
        {children}
    </BoardContext.Provider>)
}
```

`This is my reducer.`

```
export default ( state, action, activeBoard, debates,invitations) =>{
    switch(action.type) {
       case 'Add-debates':
            return { 
                ...state, 
                debates: [action.payload, ...debates]
            }
  default: 
            return state
          
    }
}
```

I get an error: TypeError: debates is not iterable
I can render debates by simply mapping it but can update reducer this way. Some help pls...

Comment: Looks like you just need to replace `...debates` in the reducer with `...state.debates`

Comment: I have tried this, didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to shallowly copy *all* levels of state from root to `debates` that you are updating as it is nested a few levels deep. The correct reference will also include the full path to that property, i.e. `state.debates` is undefined and ***not*** iterable.

```
case 'Add-debates':
  return { 
    ...state, 
    boards: {
      ...state.boards,
      Feed: {
        ...state.boards.Feed,
        debates: [action.payload, ...state.boards.Feed.debates],
      },
    },
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I didn't get any errors, but then it didn't work. Also, I'm tryin to use activeBoard to switch between rooms/ board, because there are several and I just copied one of them.

Comment: @Imhotep Can you clarify what isn't working? In your `AddDebates` action creator you pass `debates` to `payload`, but in the reducer it is treated as a single "debate" element. What is `debates` passed to the action creator? The name implies more than one "debate", like maybe an array of them, and in which case they too would need to be spread into state in the reducer, i.e. `debates: [...action.payload, ...state.boards.Feed.debates]`. IMO `action.payload` isn't a good name as it doesn't communicate what the value is or how to interact with it, I suggest using the parameter name "debates".

Comment: action.payload is an object containing some strings, and an image

Comment: I'm quite new to reducer, I just assumed action.payload was a convention

Comment: When I use the spread notation on action. payload, I get an error, not iterable

Comment: This is the action creator ``` const onSubmitDebate = e => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const newPost = {
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
            text,
            topic,
            Images : pictureUrl
        }

        AddDebates(newPost)
    } ```

Comment: @Imhotep No worries. I think "payload" is a tutorial convention since it is so generic and redux concepts can be a stumbling block for some, but I've also seen people thinking they need to pack ***all*** the action data into the payload property which only adds an unnecessary level of nesting. Ok, looks like `[action.payload, ...state.boards.Feed.debates]` is sufficient since the payload is just an object (as you were expecting). So can you describe in more detail what wasn't working with the above solution?

Comment: Thank you, your answer actually worked, the error was on my part. On a side note, I'd like to know if its possible to pass data from context to reducer. Say I declared a variable within the value of the context provider, is there a way to make this value available in the reducer?

Comment: @Imhotep Reducers are pure functions that take as arguments the current state and an action object and return the next state object. Data is passed to them in the action payloads. You could pass data from a context in an action. This being said though, redux is an abstraction built on the react Context API. I don't know your use-case but I will caution that it isn't generally recommended to duplicate state anywhere, but rather having a single source of truth is preferred. I hope this addresses your side question.

Comment: It does not, you know how you wrap the provider around a child component to pass down props. Say I have a variable defined in the context which isn't part of state, but I need this variable in the reducer. Is there a way to make this happen.  Perhaps I could show you my code so you fully understand my plight

Comment: @Imhotep Ahh, do you mean something more like a global variable that is accessible within the reducer? No, other than passing it into the reducer along with the action, the reducer function only has its little slice of state. I suppose you *could* throw that value onto `window` or some other globally defined app object but that generally is not recommended. Yes, if you want to share a link to a codesandbox (or repo) please feel free to do so.

Comment: Here's a link to my code: https://codeshare.io/GkjmEp, please follow the multiple comment as I tried to use them to explain what the problem was and how I had attempted to solve them